# How to set PDF file size using PdfDocument on Android

Tags: java, android, pdf

I have to convert some text and a small image into a PDF document on Android and for that I am using `PdfDocument` added in API 19.

The thing with this is that the PDF generated by this one is about 3 times bigger (file size) than the one generated on iOS.

Also, I tried to compress both Android and iOS PDF files with an online free compression tool and the results were:

- **iOS**: the compression couldn't do anything because was already compressed enough
- **Android**: the resulted PDF was the same as with the iOS one (about 3 times smaller)

Even if I remove the image from the doc, the resulted Android PDF takes about 2 times more space than the PDF from iOS that contains also the image (as I said, the image is small)..

As I could see, there is no method or property to set to change the quality or the compression for the PDF file.. does anyone have this issue too?

Can you please give me some suggestions? Maybe some java libraries that can just compress a pdf?

Thank you!

PS: I don't want to use a paid library for the PDF, I know that there is the iText library but I would like to use the native one.

### **UPDATE**

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4k5_sF8fzp0cmpjQjFmWE1IS3M/view?usp=sharing) you find two PDF samples one for Android and one for iOS.

The code used to generate the pdf in android is:

```
// Create a shiny new (but blank) PDF document in memory
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

            // crate a page description
            PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(612, 792, 1).create();

            // create a new page from the PageInfo
            PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

            TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
            textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            textPaint.setTextSize(12);
            textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

            Typeface textTypeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.MONOSPACE, Typeface.NORMAL);
            textPaint.setTypeface(textTypeface);

            String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.";

            StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(text, textPaint, page.getCanvas().getWidth(),
                    Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

            mTextLayout.draw(page.getCanvas());

            // do final processing of the page
            document.finishPage(page);

            mPDFFilePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "demo_android.pdf");

            try
            {
                FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mPDFFilePath);

                // write the document content
                document.writeTo(mFileOutStream);
                mFileOutStream.flush();
                mFileOutStream.close();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
            }

            //close the document
            document.close();
```

Thanks once again!

Comment: Please share a sample pair of PDFs (identical in content but different in sizes) to allow for analysis.

Comment: Looking at the samples the main reasons for the big size are **a** PDF page content streams generated by Android are not compressed and **b** text in Android content streams is drawn letter by letter with the text matrix explicitly set again before each letter. For issue **a** you might want to search for some attribute which selects compression. Issue **b**, on the other hand, looks like the Android PDF generator has an abysmal quality, looking merely like a proof-of-concept.

Comment: As an addendum to **a**: The embedded font is not compressed, either. Thus, if compression can be somehow activated in that API, the file would be quite a lot leaner.

Comment: Thanks once again for your time, I cut out the font definition and the file increased by 1KB so you are right about the font and regarding **a**, I couldn't find any flag or setting that can be used to enable/disable compression which is disappointing :(

Comment: Apparently, images are not compressed either, so in my case the generated PDFs are about 10 times bigger than they should. I haven't found a way to fix these issues, so I'm very disapointed by the current state of this API too.

Answer (score 0):

OK so until someone finds or comes with a better solution I found [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/) library which seems to do the work better than what the Android APIs are (at the moment) unfortunately.

The library might not support too complex drawings but it's ok for what I need. Also it compresses the pdf and it seems that now I can compare it with the iOS and say that it is smaller than it.

Comment: Concerning the APW library you found, you might be interested in the bug described at the bottom of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19251644/1729265); it might not yet have been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, I just hope I won't have such issues, the language is english so I have smaller chances to get into such characters but I will also look for a solution for that